# Azure Offline Authentication

Tags: asp.net, azure, xamarin.ios, azure-active-directory

Im currently looking at implementing Azure into my current xamarin.ios application. However, I have followed the tutorials on the Microsoft website for implementing Azure and more specifically the Azure authentication through the Microsoft account option.[Tutorial Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-ios-get-started-users)

What I wanted to know if its possible to have a system where-by when my app is offline (Which I will need), I want a token system where-by you can enter a PIN or password and still login to your account. Specifically the account which has already been logged into so all the user would need to do is enter a PIN when they are offline. Im not sure if this is possible but hopefully somebody can help.

Thanks
Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD Authentication allows you to grab an access token for this user with a given expiration date. You could store this locally and refresh it when the device is online. This will basically authenticate your user based on their token.

In a full offline-only scenario where you might go offline for weeks at a time (and thus the expiration token is not a feasible option) I would recommend for you to build the "PIN"-system yourself. It's quite trivial (a lot of apps do this), and you can store it locally. Make sure to store it securely (e.g. with Microsofts' secure storage nuget package): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage?tabs=ios

Comment: Ok thank you for answering. I will look into Azure Active Directory. Because I’m currently a free user, is it possible to use Azure AD?

Comment: Sorry to mess you about but I have looked into Auth0 for the Authentication as well and it seems much more user friendly for myself but a question I do have about it. Can you store the tokens offline for offline logins as the original question? Im just trying to get the best and easiest solution for me. Thanks Jamie :)

Comment: Auth0 is an alternative, but since you're working with the Microsoft ecosystem, the Active Directory would the most logical solution (as it has built-in support AND packages for Xamarin). You can store the tokens offline with no problems. They do expire though (as in, you can no longer use them online to grab information). In the end it is up to you to use this but do check the support for .NET Standard (or Xamarin) to make sure you don't have to write a lot of code to support standard functionality that's available OOTB with Azure AD!

Comment: Ok, I did look through Azure AD but none of the examples I tried in Xamarin.ios seemed to work because there are no native examples for Xamarin.ios where-as Auth0 has this. So, basically all I need to do is store the token locally or is there more to this?

Comment: The token is something you use to authorize your user to EXTERNAL services (like your own API et cetera). Your own api then calls upon Auth0: "Hi, give me the user information for this token". The token itself is quite useless.
The token is just a string (a guid in case of Azure AD). I linked a NuGet package in my official answer.

Comment: Ok so I have used this sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native and now have it working on native xamarin.ios. However, the only thing that doesn't seem to work is that when im offline (After previously logging into the app), when I close the app and re-open it, AcquireTokenSilentAsync should use the cached token in the keychain. However, this only works when im online and not offline?? Is this correct and if so, how do I get it to cache offline?